# UIActivityViewController Share Video to WeChat fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, wechat

I want to share video in my application to wechat via "UIActivityViewController"

But I got "transfer fail" message on WeChat's transfer dialog very often (alsmost 90%)

But I try to save same video to my iPhone Photos,

then share to wechat, But I never fail on it.

Is there anything I have to do before share?

My code:

```
NSMutableArray *shareFile = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSURL *shared = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:file.localFilePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file.localFilePath]) {
    [shareFile addObject: shared];
}

UIActivityViewController *_shareVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:[shareFile copy] applicationActivities:nil];

[_shareVC setCompletionWithItemsHandler:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS9.3,10.2,10.3 equipment on the same problem, share the video to WeChat friends, suggesting that "发布不成功", 100%, but in iOS8.4 can share success, use of UIActivityViewController.

Comment: Do you find any solution? I think it may be WeChat's issue. But its hard to make customer believe it.@@

Comment: NO, it may be iOS system problems also. Now i use `SLComposeViewController `temporarily.

Comment: Finally, I found the root cause, I resample my video file to 720p, it never fail again. But it also make share action slowly.